# How do I use the Firebird dot net provider under Visual Studio 2005

Tags: .net, firebird

I have installed the dot net provider and tried to reference the FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll in my windows forms c# project. 
The compiler tells me it requires a later version of the dot net runtime. My references indicate I am using v2.0.50727. I cannot see how to update this to a later version.

I am running windows 7 premium.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The Firebird .NET Provider has a different version for each version of .NET.  You are probably using the one meant for .NET 3.5 or 4.0

Comment: Cadrello, thanks, as you say, it seems these are targeted at different .net frameworks (despite the misleading headings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: Downloads from http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/

It seems that the dot net provider in NETProvider-2.7.0.zip requires the version 4 net frame work.

I found that NETProvider-2.5.2-CF.7z does run in net framework v2.0.50727 successfully.

Unfamiliar with .7z files? Need to download the 7-Zip file manager from http://www.7-zip.org/

Comment: Finally the light dawned ... the download I should have used was NETProvider-2.7.0-NET20.7z.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using 
[Version 2.0.5 for Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-net-provider/DDEX%202.0.5/FirebirdDDEXProvider-2.0.5.zip/download)
If that doesn't work you can update your project's target framework to .net 3.5 or 4, if you can in 2005. Not sure if you can. If not upgrade to vs 2008 or 2010

Comment: This link is just to the DDEX (Visual Studio integration) for Firebird dot net. I really just want the dot net provider, which is not included in this install. Thanks